# Angularjs Return result of a condition comming from a json

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm working in a app with Angularjs, node and SQL SERVER. 
I want to calculate the result of a condition that comes from a database field.

```
var chk = angular.fromJson(item.CHK1);
```

`item.chk1` is a field comming from the database, and its equal to `{"validation_cal":"item.QNT_PROPUESTA > 1000","validation_type":"BLOCK","description":"Stock mas de un año"}`

So `chk.validation_cal` is equal to `item.QNT_PROPUESTA > 1000`
and `item.QNT_PROPUESTA` is equal to 1200

I've tried:

```
console.log($rootScope.$eval(chk.validation_cal));
```

The result always is "`false`"

I supposed the problem is that Angular is not really doing the calculation of the condition.

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is validation_cal??

Comment: @Keshav is a string that comes from the database. The field item.CHK1 contains this info in the database: '{"validation_cal":"item.QNT_PROPUESTA < 1000","validation_type":"BLOCK","description":"Stock more one year"}'

Comment: Don't know if it's a typo but you have both `item.QNT_PROPUESTA < 1000` and `item.QNT_PROPUESTA > 1000` in your question

Comment: @phuzi it's a cut - paste mistake. I've tried all possibilities and is always false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem consists of that the scope doesn´t know the value of the field item.QNT_PROPUESTA. The function $eval is trying to evaluate the expression item.QNT_PROPUESTA > 1000 but before this value has to be in the rootScope.

I have tried this and it works:

```
        var chk = angular.fromJson(item.CHK1);
        $rootScope.item = { QNT_PROPUESTA : 1200 };
        console.log($rootScope.$eval(chk.validation_cal)); // true
```